# Laravel Soap Client / Server __soapCall() "unknown status" Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soap

I've been finding a solution to this problem that I had.  Please take note that I am new in Laravel but fluent in PHP.

From routes/web.php

```
Route::any('/server', 'SoapController@callServer');
Route::get('/client', function() {
    $params = array(
        'location' => 'http://localhost/soap/public/server'
        ,'uri' => 'urn://localhost/soap/public/server'
        ,'trace' => 1
    );
    $client = new \SoapClient(null, $params);
    $id_array = array('id' => '1');
    echo $client->__soapCall('getStudentName', $id_array);
});
```

From SoapController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Server;

class SoapController extends Controller
{
    public function callServer() {
        $params = array('uri' => 'soap/public/server');
        $server = new \SoapServer(null, $params);
        $server->setClass('App\Server');
        $server->handle();
    }
}
```

From app/Server.php

```
namespace App;
class Server {
    public function getStudentName($id_array) {
        return 'Student Name';
    }
}
```

When I run http://localhost/soap/public/server, it is working fine.  But when I run http://localhost/soap/public/client Laravel produces error "unknown status".

Only the __soapCall() line produces error.  The parameters were successfully transferred to the function.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php in your laravel app to white-list your server url from CSRF verification like this:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '*/images/upload',
        '*/search',
        '*/server' // add your server uri here.
    ];
}
```